# How to access a fetched Resource in a SolidJS Component before returning the JSX?

Tags: javascript, fetch, solid-js

My SolidJS component fetches a JSON object from a server and I understand how to render it using the returned JSX.

But how do I play with the fetched data before returning the JSX?

```
const fetchData = async url => {
  let results = await fetch(this.path + url)
  return await results.json()
}

function User() {
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    signIn({email: "Foo", password: "Bar"})
  }
  const signIn = obj => {
    if (obj.email && obj.password) {
      const [user] = createResource(() => fetchData("json/sign-in/" + obj.email + "/" + MD5(obj.password) ))
      
      console.log(user())
      /* undefined */
      console.log(user().name)
      /* Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') */

    }
  }
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={ handleSubmit }>Sign In</button>
    </>
  )
}

export default User
```

In the example above, the console log returns undefined or an error when trying to access a property. So how do I access this data once it has loaded? Is there a more elegant way of handing this than resorting to setTimeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `createResource` function accepts a fetcher function, which should return a promise that resolves to the fetched data. You can perform any necessary data transformations within the fetcher function itself.

Additionally, you can transform the data returned from the fetcher function within a component before rendering it.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think I can fallback on vanilla js for this one.
`const userData = server.fetchData("json/sign-in/" + obj.email + "/" + MD5(obj.password) )`
`userData.then( a => console.log(a) )`

Comment: How do I transform the data returned from the fetcher function inside a component before rendering it?

Comment: By transform i mean regular data manipulation, dont return results.json() immediately but assign it to a variable, like user, and do as you wish i.e. return user.name.